# I'm looking for a database of open source audio plug-ins that will work with several DAWs, particularly Logic.

Tags: database, plug-in

Is there a dedicated site listing many audio plug-in applications that I can scroll through? Even a blog based page would be of use?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried [their VSTs](http://www.vst4free.com/) so can't guarantee they work in Logic but in theory they should work in any VST host (any DAW that supports VST)